# How to show that the structure constant of SU(3) is invariant?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

So suppose $f_{ijk}$ is the antisymmetric structure constant of SU(3), and $D^8_{ij}(g)$ is the matrices of 8-dimensional adjoint representation of SU(3), then how to show that 
$f_{ijk}$=$D^8_{il}(g)$$D^8_{jm}(g)$$D^8_{kn}(g)$$f_{lmn}$ which shows that the structure constant is indeed invariant.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the relation holds *far* more generally than SU(3) for the adjoint. 
In fact, you can see it by the respective similarity transformations of the defining (the ***3***) in the trace defining *f*,
$$
f_{lek}= \frac{-i}{2} \operatorname{tr} ([\lambda_l,\lambda_j],\lambda_k).
$$
That is, the transformations $\lambda_k\mapsto D^{3~\dagger}(g)\lambda_lD^3(g)$ leave the trace invariant for unitary matrices.

If you just want reassurance strictly within the ***8***, OK, consider the unitary
$$D^8_{il} =\exp(1\!\!1 +i\theta\cdot T^8)_{il}= \delta_{il}+ \theta^a f_{ail} +... $$ 
You want reassurance, e.g., of invariance to lowest order in *θ*,
$$
(\delta_{il} +\theta^a f_{ail})(\delta_{jm} +\theta^b f_{bjm})(\delta_{kn} +\theta^c f_{ckn})f_{lmn} = f_{ijk}+  \theta^a (f_{ail}f_{lek}+f_{ajm}f_{imk}+ f_{akn}f_{ion}  ) + O(\theta^2).
$$
But the *O(θ)* term vanishes by the full antisymmetry of the *f*s and the Jacobi identity,
$$= f_{ijk} + O(\theta^2),
$$
and, of course, to higher orders, as well, so the expression reduces to just $f_{ijk}$, as inquired.